# Wand accessories

Tags: harry-potter

Is it necessary to have metal parts added to a wand? If so, where would a person buy them (and what's the proper name for such embellishments? "Findings"?)? I thought I would make one for my granddaughter the Potter fan.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You're asking specifically about Harry Potter, correct?  I'll retag this, but you can revert if I'm incorrect.  What kind of sources are you looking for?  Mostly we prefer questions that have answers from canonical sources.

Comment: Most Harry Potter wands are a single type of wood or several types of wood, one inlaid into the other. Some have metal bits, but not commonly.

Comment: Silencer:  https://youtu.be/j-2ZxldMO-M?si=FHDiRmNmPXJ5uWFT&t=31

Comment: It looks like you're not looking for an in-universe answer but rather how to decorate a wand you intend to gift your granddaughter? If so, I'm afraid this isn't the correct site to ask that question.

Answer (score 1):

**Is it necessary to have metal parts added to a wand?**

Wands in the Harry Potter universe (assuming that that is what your question is about) are always **made of wood.** **Metal is not necessary** to have on a wand; it is simply flavouring.

**If so, where would a person buy them (and what's the proper name for such embellishments? "Findings"?)?** *This has technically already been answered, since I said that metal add-ons are unnecessary, but I'll answer it anyway.*

I looked on the internet, and I **couldn't find a business that deals in Harry Potter wand add-ons** (or at least sells them (this makes sense, because these accessories would have to go with specific wands that they know the exact dimensions/size/shape of in order to make them fit together)). They also have **no specific name** (you can call them add-ons, accessories... really whatever floats your boat (though 'findings is a bit of on odd name for it).

Comment: What is about Lucius Malfoy's wand in the movies? It has some kind of silver colored "head" on it, I think I remember a snake? Where in-universe, would he bought it?

Comment: @Allerleirauh I think it's more likely that the snake head embellishment came with the wand that chose Lucius, instead of him buying it. There is no mention of changing wand add-ons anywhere in the series, and there is also no mention of whether it's even possible.

Comment: Interesting. Would it work then different, when Voldemort broke the snake off of the wand?

Comment: @Allerleirauh I think it would (and did) work the same. It’s still only an embellishment (though it probably came with the wand), but as far as I remember, it worked fine afterwards.